# Login failed for user ''. while trying to access database using User Assigned ManagedIdentity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, azure-managed-identity

I created all the resources for the POC :

```
############################################################################################
$grp="ManagedIdentityPOC"
$serverName="sqlservertest"
$databaseName="sqldatabase"
$loc = 'eastus'
$appname='managedidentitydemo'
$pln = 'testplan'

# CREATING RESOURCE GROUP
az group create --name $grp --location eastus

# CREATING APP SERVICE
az appservice plan create --name $pln --resource-group $grp --location $loc --sku Free
az webapp create --name $appname --plan $pln --resource-group $grp

# CREATING SQL SERVER
az sql server create -l $loc -g $grp -n $serverName -u testsqlserver -p xxxxxxxxyyyyy

# CREATING THE DATABASE
az sql db create --resource-group $grp --server $serverName --name $databaseName --edition Standard --zone-redundant false --backup-storage-redundancy Local

# ADDING A FIREWALL RULE TO CONNECT
az sql server firewall-rule create --name allowingall --server $serverName --resource-group $grp --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 255.255.255.255

# DISPLAYING INFORMATION
az sql server show --name $serverName --resource-group $grp --output json --query '[fullyQualifiedDomainName, administratorLogin]'

#SQL
CREATE TABLE Employees(Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FirstName NVARCHAR(255),LastName NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO Employees(Name) VALUES ('Emp1FirstName','Emp1LastName')
INSERT INTO Employees(Name) VALUES ('Emp2FirstName','Emp2LastName')
SELECT * FROM Employees

create user [managedidentitydemo] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [managedidentitydemo];
alter role db_datawriter add member [managedidentitydemo];

############################################################################################
```

- I have created a Managed Identity (User Assigned) using Azure portal.
- I attached that MSI with Azure App Service
- Added appropriate permissions for the MSI at Azure SQL (Database)

**ITestSQLAuthProvider.cs:**

```
public interface ITestSQLAuthProvider
{
    Task<SqlAuthenticationToken> AcquireTokenAsync(SqlAuthenticationParameters parameters);
    bool IsSupported(SqlAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod);
}


public class TestSQLAuthProvider : SqlAuthenticationProvider, IAzureSQLAuthenticationProvider
{
    private readonly string userAssignedClientId;
    private readonly string azureSQLResourceId;
    public TestSQLAuthProvider(string UserAssignedClientId, string AzureSQLResourceId)
    {
        userAssignedClientId = UserAssignedClientId;
        azureSQLResourceId = AzureSQLResourceId;
    }

    public override async Task<SqlAuthenticationToken> AcquireTokenAsync(SqlAuthenticationParameters parameters)
    {
        var _credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId});
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[]{azureSQLResourceId});
        var tokenResult = await _credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, default);
        return new SqlAuthenticationToken(tokenResult.Token, tokenResult.ExpiresOn);
    }

    public override bool IsSupported(SqlAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod) => authenticationMethod.Equals(SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity);
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string userAssignedClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MsiConfiguration:UserAssignedClientId");
        string azureSQLResourceId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MsiConfiguration:AzureSQLResourceId");

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            TestSQLAuthProvider.SetProvider(
                SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity,
                new AzureSQLAuthenticationProvider(userAssignedClientId, azureSQLResourceId));
            options.UseSqlServer(strDataDBConn);
        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

appsettings.local.json:

```
"MsiConfiguration": {
    "UserAssignedClientId": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "AzureSQLResourceId": "https://database.windows.net//.default"
  },
"Local": {
    "LocalDataDBConn": "Server=tcp:poctestsqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=poctestdb;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=500;"
  }
```

In this implementation I am using ASP.NET CORE 3.1, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version:2.2.6 and AzureSQL

On debugging the code in my local development environment, I am getting the below error:

Login failed for user ''.

Source : Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider

```
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenDbConnectionAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__12.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<FirstOrDefault_>d__165`1.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\First.cs:line 144
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__21`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Test.Repository.Generic.AppRepository`1.<GetAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Test\SampleRepository\Generic\AppRepository.cs:line 107
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't use managed identity locally, you need to authenticate with `your account` through Visual Studio. also latest package of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` support ADD auth natively without custom coding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for your response. I am using DefaultAzureCredential in this case which will work across all environments including my local development environment

Comment: What I mean is that the  `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` already uses `DefaultAzureCredential` for you. so you need to do anything

Comment: @Thomas - Does it mean that I don't have to use the custom class : TestSQLAuthProvider in this implementation. Can you please help me with me some code reference. Any help on this request is much appreciated

Comment: yeah you wouldnt need custom code. see [Using Active Directory Default authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication). You need to check tho if your version of EF is using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: In my case I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version :2.2.6 which uses System.Data.SqlClient version: 4.6.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244973/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-patro-and-thomas).

Comment: I know latest version of EF is using the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` so you may want to try to upgrade EF.